# How to position some text?

Tags: html, css, twig

Sorry for the noobie and stupid question, but I know only a bit about css and I don't know how to style my site. Here is my code:

**HTML** (Twig) :

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <img class="birthday" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/d/a/6/11970917161615154558carlitos_Balloons.svg.med.png">
            <div class="try"> 
               This friends have brithday today: 
               {% for bd in birthdays %}

               <p>
                   <a href="{{ path('friend_id', {'id': bd.id}) }}">{{ bd.name }}</a>
                      <span class="years">
                         ({{ bd.years }} years)
                       </span>
               </p>

               {% endfor %}

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFF1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  
}

p {
    margin: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a9211;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrap {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

.birthday {
    width: 49px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
    display: block;  
}

.try {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.years {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

And [this](http://s14.postimage.org/5cc2t2gbl/birthday.jpg) is what I get. The thing I want to fix is `Maria` and `Peter` to be display under `Anna` and `John`, all of them 4 centered under the label `This friends have birthday today:`. I know that it's because of the image, but I don't know how to make it look fine. :(

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add some margin-left to the try-class:
http://jsfiddle.net/VWY8N/

```
.try {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 201px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Although this solution works well, you might want to check on the other answers for corrections in greater depth.

Answer (score 2):

CSS only [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu5PY/) -

Add `float: right;` to `.try` class -

```
.try {
    /*display: block;*/ float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Edit:

You can also remove the `margins` and manage the div with `width` -

```
.try {
    /*display: block;*/ float: right; width: 500px;
    /*margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;*/
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu5PY/1/)

Comment: +1 i would use float:left and remove the margin-right, but i think floating definitely is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
.try {
width: 500px;
float: right;
margin-right: 150px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your css to the style tag in head section as shown below

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
{
    background-color: #FFFFF1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  
}

p {
    margin: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a9211;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrap {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

.birthday {
    width: 49px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
    display: block;  
}

.try {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.years {
    font-size: 12px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <img class="birthday" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/d/a/6/11970917161615154558carlitos_Balloons.svg.med.png">
            <div class="try"> 
               This friends have brithday today: 
               {% for bd in birthdays %}

               <p>
                   <a href="{{ path('friend_id', {'id': bd.id}) }}">{{ bd.name }}</a>
                      <span class="years">
                         ({{ bd.years }} years)
                       </span>
               </p>

               {% endfor %}

            </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include css using <style type="text/css">
<!--
/* ... CSS code ... */
-->
</style>

Comment: @StefanNeubert tat is not mandatory if you are using html5 doctype

Comment: @Sowmya: you're right, sorry for this. But still - Ujwal's answer is not a solution to the question.

Comment: @StefanNeubert yes but i didn't comment on answer. I jus told u tats it :)